# Load a javascript first

Tags: javascript

In the home-page of my website, I have put an intro-video which is not at the top. I want my visitors to view the intro video first. For this, I have used autoscroll:

```
<script>
function pageScroll() {
        window.scrollBy(245,600); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
}</script>
```

and then in the body:

```
<body onload="pageScroll()"> 
.....
</body>
```

But, the issue is that the browsers take a long time to autoscroll. Visitors reach the swf flash video only when half of it is already over (it is a short 10 sec video). How do I make the browsers follow this javascript first before anything else? [There are other javascripts on the website too]

Thanx in advance...

Comment: Why don't you start playing the video after the scroll is done?

Comment: Why not move the video when it finishes instead of the user before it starts.

Comment: BTW, it's a VERY bad user experience.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a sample for a CSS only solution at http://jsfiddle.net/gqJ9e/

The only thing is that you don't have the video on the page later on.

HTML

```
<input id="switch" type="checkbox">
<div class="video">
    <label for="switch">CLOSE</label>
    <p>VIDEO MESSAGE</p>
</div>
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <p>PAGE CONTENT</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.page-wrapper,
#switch,
#switch:checked+.video {
    display:none;
}

#switch:checked+.video+.page-wrapper {
    display:block;
}
```

**Alternative solution** to still have the video on the page at the bottom http://jsfiddle.net/gqJ9e/1/

HTML

```
<input id="switch" type="checkbox">
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <p>PAGE CONTENT</p>
</div>
<div class="video">
    <label for="switch">CLOSE</label>
    <p>VIDEO MESSAGE</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.page-wrapper,
#switch,
#switch:checked+.video,
#switch:checked+.page-wrapper+.video>label {
    display:none;
}

#switch:checked+.page-wrapper {
    display:block;
}
```